# android textview and buttons automove

Tags: android, android-layout

When I try to change the location of my button in my main.xml, my textviews and edittexts moves somewhere irrevelant. I used only one RelativeLayout and all buttons and textviews are in that layout. Or when I try to change the id of the button, textviews move around again and after I locate all again, when I try to open emulator, it doesn't even open without error in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) means that you should position the elements *relatively* to each other. It uses positioning attributes such as `android:layout_toRightOf="..."` that refer to the ID of another view that should be displayed left of the current view.

If you would like to arrange your views just by their position in your XML document, use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

Comment: I'm new on android programming and lack of xml layouts knowledge. Cant I put the buttons and textviews without using layouts? I dont want to put them in order.

Comment: Well, you _may_ align and position all your elements in a pure programmatical way, but let me tell you that the XML approach makes it much easier. Just follow the links to RelativeLayout/LinearLayout that I provided above and read how to use layout attributes there.